# Question about principle ideals and polynomials and quotient ring construction?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

Say I have a ring of polynomials in $R[x]$. I wish to define the quotient group $R[x]/<x^2+1>$.

My question lies in the ideal generated by $<x^2 + 1>$. This is the set of all numbers such that if we take every element of $R$ it is

$I = r(x^2+1) $.

So it is every possible multiple of $x^2 + 1$. Is this correct, thus far?

Okay now, if this is our ideal, we wish to define a ring structure from creating additive cosets of this ideal. Is each element then from the quotient group described above equal to:

$R + I$

With the additive identity being equal to $0 + I$ and the Unity $1$ being equal to $ 1 + I$?

Is this all correct?

Comment: You are taking the ideal $<x^2+1>$ in $R[X]$, thus $<x^2+1> = \{ p\in R[X] | p = gf, g \in R[X]\}$. So it is every possible polynomial multiple of $x^2+1$.

Comment: What does the f mean in your set Construction? And what are some elements in this set? Is it $2(x^2 +1) $ in this set? Ohhh wait. It is this polynomial being multiplied by EVERY polynomial in R[x]? That's the ideal?

Comment: His $f$ is $x^2 + 1$.

Comment: @Sam So it's $x^2 + 1$ being multiplied by every element in $R[x]$ which is the ideal, I'll denote $I$ And this ideal plus every $r \in R$ such that $ r + I$ is an additive coset. And all such cosets make up this quotient group. Is this a correct construction? When r = 0, this will be the identity, and when r = 1 this will be unity?

Comment: Yup, that's it.  Don't forget that in general we require ideals to be closed under addition (here it happens "automatically").

Comment: I got another question. Why is it that $x^2 + 1$ + $<x^2 + 1>$ = to zero in this quotient ring? Shouldn't it be the zero polynomial?